# Undefined reference to 'function'

Tags: c, compilation, cmake

i am trying to compile a .c-file (lets call this one (p2)), which uses functions from another .c-file (p1). I created a header-file for (p1), where all the functions are defined.

This header-file is included in (p2) and in my CMakeLists.txt i added the following lines:

```
# A2
set(SOURCES_A2
        src/p2.c
        src/p1.h)
add_executable(p2 ${SOURCES_A2})
```

When i try to compile with `make p2` i get the `message undefined reference to 'function'`, where `function` is a function from (p1). Did i forgot to add something more to the CMake file ?

I would appreciate any help and if you need any code, then just say so.

Greetings

Comment: Surely if p2 relies on p1, you need to add p1 to the sources.

Comment: you mean, that i have to add p1.c to the CMake file too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undefined reference means the linker couldn't find the function anywhere. This usually means you forgot to specify the object file you're in. An example of how to resolve this using gcc.

```
gcc -c -o p1.o p1.c
gcc -c -o p2.o p2.c
gcc -o program p1.o p2.o
```

The first step compiles p1.c into an object file, and doesn't link it yet (-c). So does the second step, but instead it compiles p2.c. The final steps links the created object files together and creates the final program.

In your case, you can add this to your make command by adding src/p1.c to your sources. You seem to have forgotten to add it:

```
set(SOURCES_A2
    src/p2.c
    src/p1.h
    src/p1.c)
add_executable(p2 ${SOURCES_A2})
```

Comment: the problem is, that p1.c also has a main(). That would cause another error wouldn't it ?

Comment: Why does it also have a main? Move the common function to p3 and include that

Comment: p1.c contains some I/O, but actually i could get rid of the main there. Thank you!